# Multiple kubernetes pods with Azure Eventhubs subscription redundancy

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-eventhub

I am working in a microservice architecture and deploying them in k8s. For communication among different application, we are using Azure eventhub to publish and subscribe events. My question is if multiple instances(POD) of an application are running, then the subscribed event callback will be triggered in single POD or in each POD?

Do i need to segregate the PODs in different consumer group?

Answer (score 0):

At any given time only one processor must read events from a consumer group. Do not share a consumer group between different receivers! Important: They need to actively read, there is no "callback".

So if you have multiple consumers that you want to receive each event, then yes, you need to have multiple consumer groups, one for each pod in your case.

But since you are talking about publish-subscribe, maybe something like Azure Service Bus Topics might actually better suited for your scenario?!